# Firefox crashed with message: "used up all the available ids"

Tags: firefox, crash

After running a webapp for a few days in Mozilla Firefox ESR 52.5.0, the browser crashed. Found in the crash report is the following line:

> MozCrashReason=MOZ_CRASH(used up all the available ids)

I am wondering if anyone has any idea what this exactly means, and if there's anything we can do from a development standpoint to prevent this from happening.

There is very little on this message that I could find on Google, other than the actual line of source code: https://github.com/mozilla/positron/blob/master/accessible/windows/msaa/IDSet.h#L76

Thanks in advance!

Comment: line 22 says: 
` * On windows an accessible's id must be a negative 32 bit integer. It is
 * important to support recycling arbitrary IDs because accessibles can be
 * created and destroyed at any time in the life of a page.`

what kind of page is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Positron is a fork of Firefox, which is why you found this error in its codebase.

I'm unfamiliar with the Firefox code that caused the crash, but at first glance, it looks like it generates identifiers for Accessible objects, which enable screen readers and other assistive technologies to access the content of web pages.

If your webapp is causing Firefox to run out of those IDs, then my first suspicion is that the app is leaking DOM elements (i.e. removing them from the DOM but retaining some reference to them, so they never get garbage-collected and release their accessible IDs for reuse) or creating many elements quickly (f.e. because of an infinite loop).

But that's just a hunch. You could try reporting the problem as a bug in Firefox:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=Disability%20Access%20APIs

However, the problem may turn out to be in your code rather than in the browser, so I'd investigate your code first, then ask for help in the Accessibility community (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility#Join_the_Accessibility_community), before reporting a bug.

Comment: Gotcha, that's a good theory; it's certainly possible our website is making a lot of elements. However, on the about:support page, Accessibility > Activated is set to false. Do you know why the code to create Accessible IDs would even be running if the Accessibility feature is supposedly off?

Comment: I don't know the circumstances under which accessible IDs are created, but https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/accessibility-services#w_what-is-the-accessibility-service-indicator suggests that the accessibility service can be activated unless the user explicitly disables it in their preferences. So perhaps the accessibility service creates IDs for pages in case an assistive technology later activates the service for the page.